# Control encoding when parsing SPSS file using package memisc

Tags: r, encoding, utf-8, spss, latin1

I have been given a SPSS system file that I would like to analyse using R. I am using the following magic for parsing the file into R.

```
library(memisc)
foo <- spss.system.file("foobar.sav")
bar <- subset(foo, select=c(var1,var2,var3))
```

When having a look at the parsed data, you get the following:

```
> bar
Data set with 379 observations and 3 variables

var1       var2        var3
1      gut    weiblich      Herbst
2      gut mnlich      Sommer
3      gut mnlich      Sommer
4      gut mnlich      Winter
5      gut mnlich Fr�hling
6      gut mnlich Fr�hling
7      gut    weiblich Fr�hling
.
.
.
25      gut    weiblich Fr�hling
.. ........ ........... ...........
(27 of 379 observations shown)
```

I guess you get the idea.  I am relatively sure that the .sav-file has been saved using the latin1-encoding.  How can I tell `spss.system.file()` to use this encoding when parsing the SPSS-file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you everyone for your help. I will be answering my own question. `spss.system.file()` reads strings contained in SPSS files as-is, without any translation. The resulting strings therefore do not contain any encoding information.  The `memisc` package contains a function `Iconv`, however, that does exactly what the Unix function `iconv` would do.

```
> library(memisc)
> foo <- spss.system.file("foobar.sav")
> foo <- Iconv(foo,from="Latin1",to="UTF-8")
> foo <- as.data.frame(as.data.set(foo))
> head(foo$Geschlecht)
[1] weiblich männlich männlich männlich männlich männlich
Levels: männlich weiblich
```

All the best.

Answer (score 0):

This problem could be specific to `memisc` package. As a quick solution try `read.spss` function of `foreign` package, if you do not want to stick to memisc. Consider also to add `memisc` tag to your question.

Comment: I do have the suspicion that it is indeed a problem of the `memisc` package as I have requested the sav-file to be saved in utf-8. The parsed result is now: m\xe4nnlich instead of the mnlich. The `read.spss` function seems to be outdated and does -- unfortunately -- not work, which is why I am using `memisc`. Adding a tag `memics` does not work, as it would need 5000 votes to make it a tag.

Answer (score 0):

That output indicates clearly that the function is not taking into account the character encoding in the file or that the encoding is not correctly declared.  Those ? characters indicate a misinterpreted or incorrectly written character.  I expected them to be u-umlauts, but in code page 1252 e4 is actually a-umlaut.

Sav files have their encoding marked, so it should be respected.  If the file was created by SPSS, the marking will be correct, however we have seen cases where sav files written by third-party code does not mark the file correctly.

I'm pretty sure that this file is actually written in code page 1252, but the encoding is probably declared, incorrectly, as utf-8, assuming that the display above would actually represent extended characters properly.

The SPSS SYSFILE INFO command will show the declared encoding, if any, but you can also look at a hex dump of the first part of the file and see it.